# Environment Variables when script run by cron

Tags: python, linux, cron, environment-variables

I have a Python script which uses environment variables. This script works exactly as planned when run directly; however, I would like to run it as a cron job every minute for the time being.

Currently in my `cron.` directory I have a file called `scrapers` containing:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/python3.5 /code/scraper.py
```

This runs the Python script but the script fails, as in the script I use two environment variables.

I read I should add `SHELL=/bin/bash` to the cron file, so I did, but this didn't help.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * root /usr/bin/python3.5 /code/scraper.py
```

Then I read

> In the crontab, before you command, add `. $HOME/.profile`.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * . $HOME/.profile; root /usr/bin/python3.5 /code/scraper.py
```

but this caused the cron to stop running altogether. What is the best way of 'sending' the env variables to the cron?

Comment: try adding `source ~/.bashrc && command` or the file where your env variables are declared and see if it works.

Comment: @franklinsijo Sorry, I'm not quite sure what I should be doing. The env variables are declared in docker-compose file when setting up the containers.

Comment: and those variables are the ones to be used by scraper.py?

Comment: @franklinsijo yes.

Comment: If `scraper.py` is independent of docker, You can save those variables to a file and use them in the cron.

Comment: It is independent but the env variables are a username and password so I'd prefer not to store them in a file. I know env variables aren't exactly overly secure either but at least they are slightly more secure.

Comment: The env variables are also set in a file. How there is a difference in security?

Comment: @franklinsijo Once the docker image has been built I can delete the file that contained the env variables. Either way this is a bit off topic. I'd be interested to know if this was possible in case I needed it for other env variables in the future.

Comment: AFAIK, env variables has to be set in a file (profile files) to be available even after the session is closed. Or you can use `export` command to set the variable for that session.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of executing the whole `~/.profile` what I'd do is move the variables that must be shared between your `cron` jobs and the account that has the profile, then I'd source these both in `~/.profile` and in the cron job.

The last attempt you show in the question is not properly formatted. The user id should be coming right after the scheduling information, but you've added the sourcing of the profile before the user id, which surely cannot work.

Here's an example setup that I've tested here:

```
*/1 * * * * someuser . /tmp/t10/setenv && /usr/bin/python /tmp/t10/test.py
```

I've set it to execute every minute for testing purposes. Replace `someuser` with something that makes sense. The `/tmp/t10/setenv` script I used had this:

```
export FOO=foovalue
export BAR=barvalue
```

The `/tmp/t10/test.py` file had this:

```
import os

print os.environ["FOO"], os.environ["BAR"]
```

My cron emails me the output of the scripts it runs. I got an email with this output:

```
foovalue barvalue
```

Comment: `setenv && test.py`, is equivalent to a system call of `test.py` in `setenv `, it will and should definitely work, better approach than mine to put system call of test.py in one file. I like this approach.

Comment: Why source it in `~/.profile`? Isn't sourcing in the cronjob enough?

Comment: You have to source it in `~/.profile` if you still want your `~/.profile` to work like it did before. If you don't want that, then you don't have to source it in `~/.profile`.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this since I use `zsh`, but it's not working. I have two env vars in `~/.env`, my .py file sources `.env` and reads them using `os.environ`, and this is my cron job: `*/2 * * * * ~/.env && ~/Documents/Dev/site_monitor/monitor_env/bin/python ~/Documents/Dev/site_monitor/monitor.py`. The problem is that I get `None` for both vars when I `print` them in the cron job; they still `print` correctly in VS Code. Originally, the cron job told me there was a permissions error with `.env`, but I fixed that, so I know it's reading it. I couldn't get the job working with a username

Comment: @MarioParra You are missing the `.` (source) before `~/.env`. Without it, you are running `.env` in a subshell whose variables cease to exist when it exits, and thus they are not available to the rest of the `cron` job.

Comment: @tripleee I noticed right after I posted this. That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can set the env variable inline:

`* * * * * root ENV_VAR=VALUE /usr/bin/python3.5 /code/scraper.py`

Another way is use [honcho](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho) that you can pass a file with env variables.

`honcho -e /path/to/.env run /code/scraper.py`

Comment: Is there a way to have all env values passed through the cron?

Comment: Env variables are inherited from the parent process.

Answer (score 4):

You can add it to the top of your crontab and keep it out of version control. Let's say the environment variable causing you difficulty is `export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="FOOBAR_1241243124312341234"`:

## crontab

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="FOOBAR_1241243124312341234"

SCRIPT_NAME = my_cool_script
20 21 * * 1-5 bash ~/git_repo/cronjobs/$SCRIPT_NAME.sh 2&>1 | tee ~/git_repo/cronjobs/logs/$SCRIPT_NAME.log
```

## my_cool_script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
~/anaconda3/envs/django/bin/python ~/git_repo/django_project/manage.py run_command
```

This has worked well for me when the environment variables in question need to be kept secret and the loading of existing .bashrc does not play nice for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify your two environment variables by this:

```
* * * * * root env A=1 B=2 /usr/bin/python3.5 /code/scraper.py
```

`env` is a system program that runs a specified program with additional variables:

```
$ env A=1 B=2 /bin/sh -c 'echo $A$B'  # or just 'sh': would search in $PATH
12
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the approach I like, write a script to set environment and execute the script with its parameters as its parameters

set_env_to_process.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "TEST_VAR before export is: <$TEST_VAR>"

export TEST_VAR=/opt/loca/netcdf
echo "TEST_VAR after export is: <$TEST_VAR>"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/python3.5
export PYTHTONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/my/installed/pythonpath

# execute command and its parameters as input for this script
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No command to execute"
else
    echo "Execute commands with its parameters: $@"
    eval $@
fi
```

usage

`/usr/bin/python3.5 /code/scraper.py`are taken as input for `set_env_to_process.sh`
`set_env_to_process.sh` set the correct env for script to run

It could be used as command line, cron, sudo, ssh to setup env

```
 * * * * * root set_env_to_process.sh /usr/bin/python3.5 /code/scraper.py
```