# standalone Shell script working fine but not working with crontab

Tags: shell, cron

I have a shell script which has the below statements. It works fine while executing stand alone.

```
$ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $BDBUSER@$LINKNAME/$BDBPASSWORD <<EOF
  DECLARE
  COUNT1 NUMBER:=0;
  BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TABLE1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE TABLE1 AS SELECT * FROM $SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE2@DBLINKNAME';
  END;
  /

EOF
```

But when I call this ffrom crontab, it fails. My crontab looks like

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/sh /home/mig/Test.sh > /home/mig/Test.txt
```

I am getting the following error in log.

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment Variables when python script run by cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114982/environment-variables-when-python-script-run-by-cron)

Comment: Your script contains reference to `ORACLEHOME`, while the error message mentions `ORACLE_HOME`. Is that intentional? Also, how are you setting all the variables used in the script?

Comment: I have another file in which I have initialized the variables and calling that script from my main script.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the this line on the top of your shell script.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/home/directory
```

Get the value of ORACLE_HOME environment variable using  echo command on your shell

Comment: I have another script where I have exported the oracle home directory in a variable and that script is called in this one.                                                      script1: export ORACLEHOME='/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1'                            script2: source script1.sh

Comment: Try adding in this one also. Don't know the exact reason but I hope that it would work

Comment: The error is asking to set ORACLE_HOME and you set ORACLEHOME and reference that's why error is coming

Answer (score 1):

Oracle needs `ORACLE_HOME` and your script needs `ORACLEHOME`.
Needless to say it would be better to change your script(s) into using ORACLE_HOME, but that's not the root cause of your problem.

The crontab commands will skip your login scripts. I think ORACLE_HOME is set in your `.profile`, so execute this.

```
*/1 * * * * source  ~/.profile; /bin/sh /home/mig/Test.sh > /home/mig/Test.txt
```