# Python script works manually, but not from cron job

Tags: bash, python-3.x

I have a Python script that gets a piece of data from an environment variable like so:

```
password = os.environ["SomePassword"]
```

The script works as expected when I run it manually, however when the script is in a shell file and run by a cron job it fails on that line with a "KeyError", which I assume is it not finding the variable.

Also, when I run any of the below as the same user that runs the cron job, I see the variable as expected.

```
echo $SomePassword
env
printenv
```

What's going on and how do I resolve this?

**UPDATE:**
I was able to resolve this by reading the suggested duplicate question - however, that question does not describe the root issue, which may be of interest to others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment Variables when python script run by cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114982/environment-variables-when-python-script-run-by-cron)

Comment: Thanks, that must have been the one post I hadn't read. That lead me to add this to my bash script "source /home/myuser/.profile" and that worked. I'd still like to understand how this works. I ran it manually using the same user the cron job runs as and it works fine - what's different about the bash script and cron job?

Comment: Cron jobs are run by a system user which does not know anything about your env, namely, does not read your .bashrc or .profile. So whatever you put there during your login session will not be present by default when cron runs. `man 5 crontab` will tell you what env vars are present plus a lot of good info.

Comment: The crontab is set up and run under UserX, so it's odd to me that it can't see it's own profile. When I sudo into UserX, I can see the variables.

Comment: cron is run by `root` user. su to root and chck if your env vars are there, they should not.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the environment variables are not declared and assigned with a value.

It works when you run it manually, because when you logged in, various environment scripts ran (e.g. ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, possibly others like /etc/bashrc) and they have done this.

You can test this by creating a simple script that saves all the environment variables into a file and schedule it with cron. After it ran, check what's in the file.