# Python cannot access environment variables when run via Cron

Tags: python, cron

I have a number of environment variables set, which I utilize in python scripts. When I run manually it works without a problem. When I schedule it to run via Cron, the variables do not return anything. I am using MacOS to develop and anticipate to automate this on a Raspberry Pi eventually.

Without having to create new variables inline (which will require two places to update) how can I utilize environment variables in python scripts when run via Cron?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Environment Variables when python script run by cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114982/environment-variables-when-python-script-run-by-cron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the scheduling information place . {path you want to share}

```
* * * * * . {path to the env file} {script to run}
```