# Script unable to access environment vars only in cron job

Tags: python, environment-variables

I've written a Python scraper that checks the status code of a URLs using the `requests` library and sends me an email using Gmail. I've got my SMTP credentials saved in a separate file, `~/.zshenv` (macOS), which I had to manually create and I'm `import`'ing `os`. If I manually run the file in my editor, it works as expected, I see the credentials `print`'ed, and the email is sent, but when the scraper runs on a cron job, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ourcore/Documents/Dev/site_monitor/monitor.py", line 16, in notify_user
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 732, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 645, in auth
    authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

It seems like it can't access the SMTP credentials because the cron job logs `print` my credentials as `None` for the username and password. Could it be a permissions issue? I've read other questions, but they were using Docker or another OS.

Comment: can you print(authobject(challenge)) ?

Comment: `cron` does not run Zsh, and even if it does, it might not load `.zshenv` unless you specifically force it to. The standard solution is to break out this specific configuration to a separate file, and source (`.`) that from both your `.zshenv` and the particular `cron` job which requires it.

Comment: @tripleee Makes sense, but it's not working for me. I left a comment with my issue on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170345/2086597)